# Better way to determine API Endpoint in DelegatingHandler than string compare?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a WebAPI project, and have a custom MessageHandler class inheriting from DelegatingHandler.  If a request is aimed at a specific controller endpoint, I need to do something different than all other requests.

**My question is: Is there a better way to accomplish this than by string comparison against the RequestUri?**

```
public class CustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get 
          && request.RequestUri.Segments.Last().Trim('/').Equals("Session", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      ...
   }
}
```

Feels clunky to me, but I have not yet been able to find a better method than the above.

Comment: I think that a `DelegatingHandler` is too early in the pipeline unless you want to go with the solution you proposed. Have a look at this pipeline poster: http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster-grayscale.pdf